# BinaryReader ReadSingle()

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7, binaryreader

In my WP7 app, I have used BinaryReader class's ReadSingle() method to read a floating point value from a stream. It works fine and gives the correct value when I run the code on Emulator. But When I run the same code on device, it always gives 0.0 as value. I have no idea why this happens. Please help solve this issue.

Comment: Where are you picking your stream from?

Comment: @KooKiz : The stream is a response comes from server as a result of a HttpWebRequest.

Comment: I guess you should print the whole response using a StreamReader. Maybe the server is returning an error for some reason.

Comment: Server does not return any error. It always works fine on emulator.

Comment: When you run the code from the device, is your device plugged to the computer? If plugged, it will use your computer's connection. If not plugged, it will use your mobile operator connection. Therefore, the server can return different results. But if you're sure that's not the case, that's fine. Still, this '0.0' doesn't come out of nowhere. Maybe add some code, so we can check if there's something wrong?

Comment: Disconnect the device from the Desktop and try by running the application. I am also experienced the same.